# Syntax for configuation

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am sorry for this silly question. I am new to jQuery and don't understand this syntax

```
<input id="autocomplete" />
<script>
    $("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
        animation: false
    });
</script>
```

How can we just call the kendoAutoComplete() function on the element with id = autoComplete ?

Is kendoAutoComplete a jQuery function that kendo has? Can we assign any such function to any element ?

This kendoAutoComplete takes an object that as parameter with properties like animation for configuring the element ?

Comment: [This is extremely basic](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), but should explain the core underlying concept for how _Kendo UI_ extends the default _jQuery_ functionality. It's nothing more than a very complex and well defined plugin that provides built-in widgets all of which, as you note, allow for customization and configuration..

Comment: Yes, Kendo extends jQuery like any other jQuery plugin. Clearly it takes a configuration object (also like many jQuery plugins).